# Getting a Jira Issue via OAuth Authentication using Postman

Tags: oauth, jira, postman

I am trying to GET an issue in Jira using POSTMAN. I have selected Type as OAuth 1.0. For that it is asking me some fields mentioned below. I have generated  Token and Token Secret which I am passing to it. I have also configured my generic application to Jira in Application links. I am not aware of what to be passed in Consumer Secret and Signature Method (what should be the signature method). I am currently selecting HMAC-SHA1. For rest of the fields it is generating values based on the parameters passed above.

```
Consumer Key : hardcoded-consumer
Consumer Secret : ?? (What should I pass here)
Token : ojn33TZALMlvp5eCa6HeErDSx9K8LL6A
Token Secret : inHfn2QFJkkYkWQ8FxT9mXkdcoNxYPf5
Signature Method : HMAC-SHA1
Timestamp : 1474290363 (Generated value)
Nonce : x1hs2v (Generated value)
Version : 1.0 (Generated value)
Realm : (It is optional)
```

After hitting my jira Url it is giving me oauth_problem=token_rejected error. Can anyone tell me where I am making the mistake?

Here is the Jira URL which I am hitting :

```
http://bmh1060149:8080/rest/api/2/issue/NWFM-1 (NWFM-1 is the Jira issue)
```

Please find the below screen shot for more reference.

[image: OAuthInPostman]

Answer (score 4):

After little bit of research I found the answer. Once we get the access token we can directly pass that to your Jira Url. There is no need to pass all those parameters.

To get all issue types we can use the following URL and passing access token as an argument.

```
http://bmh1060149:8080/rest/api/2/issuetype?access_token=euyyIxB6q5waBHeZ9zB7kGV21GRNNOud
```

Please see the attached screen shot for more reference.

[image: HittingURLwithAccessToken]

[image: ResponseJSONData]

Comment: simply passing access token is not working. I am passing the access token like this:
`http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issuetype?access_token=YLebKLCapdv0KOPhZhu65dAUsLBTfPGx`

Comment: Also not working on my end. May be you guys have an updated solution for this?