# "Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it." - JIRA REST API using Postman with OAuth

Tags: android, jira, postman, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to login using OAuth and use JIRA REST APIs.
I followed [this doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-oauth-authentication/).

I was able to get the access_token and make successful calls using terminal with the sample client provided by JIRA.
Ex -:

```
java -jar OAuthTutorialClient-1.0.jar request https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/ABC-130
```

Above command is working fine and returning me the data.

However, my final aim is to use the APIs in my Android app. So I tried with Postman first. I am making a get request with URL `https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/ABC-130` and passing `access_token` in headers.

I am getting below error:

```
{
"errorMessages": [
    "Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."
],
"errors": {}}
```

I think I am making doing something wrong in using OAuth in Postman.
[image]

Comment: Did you pass in the rest call the token?

Comment: @RobertoRusso I added access_token key in header with the value of access token. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Added screenshot in issue description above.

Comment: This user seems to have found a solution to your problem: [Getting a Jira Issue via OAuth Authentication using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574851/getting-a-jira-issue-via-oauth-authentication-using-postman)

Answer (score -4):

go to authentication > select authentication type in the drop-down

1) click on my picture > bottom left

2) select profile

3) click 'manage your account'

4) click 'security

5) click 'create and manage API tokens'

I think this is enough to solve that error