# How to call jira server rest api using oauth access token from postman.?

Tags: oauth, jira

Simply passing it like http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issuetype?access_token=YLebKLCapdv0KOPhZhu65dAUsLBTfPGx 
as told by this post [Getting a Jira Issue via OAuth Authentication using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574851/getting-a-jira-issue-via-oauth-authentication-using-postman)
is not working

Answer (score 0):

After researching I came to realize that Jira Rest Access Token is currently only available for Jira Cloud.

The server's API access token is still under Atlassian's gathering interest phase. You can vote on this ticket [JRASERVER-67869](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-67869?_ga=2.104499008.1721843271.1575713220-275679834.1552639324)

Consider using Basic Authentication on jira Server for the time being

The thread from Atlassian Community for [Jira Server API Token](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Create-API-token-for-a-user-in-Jira-Server-Locally/qaq-p/834864)

Comment: i want to integrate it with 3rd party app to update issue status in jira when certain events occur . i cannot tell users to put username and password  in the 3rd party web app.

Comment: Zephyr Enterprise requests to create a user for their 3rd party application. Maybe there is a way to do it from the Atlas-SDK