# Can't connect to Jira cloud REST API

Tags: c#, rest, jira-rest-api

I've been tasked to update some internal software (C# Windows application) that used the old Jira SOAP protocol to use the newer REST API.  I've searched and tried several examples but none have worked for me, most coming back with the error message "Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to view it".

Here's an example of what I'm currently trying to use [Mike Jansen - JiraRestClient.NET](https://bitbucket.org/MikeJansen/jirarestclient.net/src/f77556b2be7e/)

Test Code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class JiraRestClientTest
{
    [Test]
    public void OneTest()
    {
        IJiraRestClient client = new JiraRestClient("https://xxxx.atlassian.net", "myemail@domain.com", "MyPassword");
        IJiraIssue issue = client.GetIssue("TASR-456");

        Assert.AreEqual("TASR-456", issue.Key);
        Assert.IsFalse(issue.IsSubtask);
    }
}
```

I've verified that I can log into Jira with the supplied credentials and I can view the given issue as well, so I'm not sure why I'm getting that error.

**UPDATE**
I used Postman and Insomnia to test the API and both return the same error.  I'm beginning to think this error is very generic because I can put invalid user credentials in and I get the same error.

**UPDATE #2**
Here's the JSON error message from Postman:

```
{
"errorMessages": [
    "Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."
],
"errors": {}
}
```

Comment: I do not see a `GetIssue` defined under [JiraRestClient](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client-parent/4.0.0/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/api/JiraRestClient.html) ?   Is that because I am looking in the wrong place ?

Comment: I see it in IJiraRestClient:
`IJiraRestResponse Get(string resource);`

Comment: @Robert did you verify that your Jira account has API access rights? If you can login into Jira it does not mean you can use the API - we had a similar issue and after our Jira admin gave us the rights we could access the data.

Comment: Well I created an API Key for my login but I'll have to check with IT to make sure my account actually has API access rights.

Comment: Can you post the full contents of the returned (error)message from your postman test? (I think it's a JSON message ?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a Jira Issue via OAuth Authentication using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574851/getting-a-jira-issue-via-oauth-authentication-using-postman), with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39576996/724039) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after reading (what seemed like) hundreds of articles.  I generated an API Token and had to use that token as the PASSWORD in the `JiraRestClient` call.  Once I did that, everything worked....hope this helps someone else who's had the same issues!

Comment: It tells that the error message "or you do not have permission" was right, which is almost always the case....